# Is it a good idea to have a global variable for document in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML-file and a JS-file. Here they are:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz Maker for Moodle - EGE Exam</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
    <script> doc = document; </script>
</head>
```

JS:

```
var doc;    
function printSomething() {
    doc.writeln("HELLO");

}
```

You see what I'm doing here: I create a global variable to store my **document** there and then I use is the function. If I don't do it, and write `document.writeln("HELLO")`, the function doesn't work.

However, I assume this is a bad practice. If I'm right, is there a correct way of making my document available to all functions in all JS-files I might want to attach later on?

Comment: The built-in document is a global variable

Comment: The use of global variables are frowned upon because of the possibility of code that's elsewhere that could be using variables with the same name. If you're concerned you can [namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/881556/2813224) your script.

Comment: Side note: write/writeln are interesting methods. I'd recommend reading about them https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write to clearly understand what you should expect.

Comment: @IAmDranged 

Hm.. Then why doesn't my function in the separate file work if I do not pass the document as a parameter?

Comment: Is there any error printed out to the console? If so what is it? Could you provide the complete code?